# Potential Energy of Conservative Forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, potential-energy, conservative-field

> For a conservative force, its associated potential energy at position $\mathbf{r}$ is
>   $$U(\mathbf{r}) = - \int_{\mathbf{r}_{0}}^{\mathbf{r}} \mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r'}) \cdot \text{d} \mathbf{r'}$$
>
> I've tried to calculate the potential energy of the force $\mathbf{F} = (y, x, 0)$. I know that the force is conservative as it only depends on position $\mathbf{r}$, and $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = \mathbf{0}$. Also, I know its potential energy should be $U = -xy$, using the relationship that $\mathbf{F} = - \nabla U$. But my answer is $-2xy$.
>
> Can anyone see the mistake I have made below?

Taking $\mathbf{r}_{0}$ to be the origin. Then,
\begin{align}
U(\mathbf{r}) &= - \int_{0}^{\mathbf{r}}
\begin{pmatrix}
y' \\
x' \\
0
\end{pmatrix} \cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
\text{d} x' \\
\text{d} y' \\
\text{d} z'
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= - \int_{0}^{\mathbf{r}} (y' ~ \text{d} x' + x' ~ \text{d} y' + 0 ~ \text{d} z') \\
&= - \LARGE[ \normalsize x'y' + x'y' + 0 \LARGE]_{\normalsize 0}^{\normalsize \mathbf{r}} \\
&= - \LARGE[ \normalsize 2x'y' \LARGE]_{\normalsize 0}^{\normalsize \mathbf{r}} \\
&= -2xy
\end{align}

> > EDIT: I think I've found the answer.
> >     \begin{align}
> > U(\mathbf{r}) &= - \int_{0}^{x} F_{x}(x,0,0) ~ \text{d} x' - \int_{0}^{y} F_{y}(x,y,0) ~ \text{d} y' - \int_{0}^{z} F_{z}(x,y,z) ~ \text{d} z' \\
> > &= - \int_{0}^{x} 0 ~ \text{d} x' - \int_{0}^{y} x ~ \text{d} y' - \int_{0}^{z} 0 ~ \text{d} z' \\
> > &= 0 - \LARGE[ \normalsize xy' \LARGE]_{\normalsize y' = 0}^{\normalsize y' = y} \\
> > &= -xy
> > \end{align}
> >
> > Is this now correct?

Comment: Your integral needs to be a path integral. What path are you integrating over?

Comment: @probably_someone I don't have a path. I have been given the force $\mathbf{F} = (y, x, 0)$, and to determine the potential energy if $\mathbf{F}$ is conservative. Also, assume that $U$ is chosen to be zero at the origin.

Comment: What @probably_someone says is true. This was also something I overlooked when I was first learning how to do problems like these. In general you can't do these integrals like you learn in introductory calculus.

Comment: Your new edit is technically correct, but with just the work there is no way to know if you actually understand what you are doing with those integrals.

Comment: The edit is incorrect. It's mixing up $x$ (the coordinate) and $x'$ (the integration variable); for example, apparently $F$ has no dependence on $x'$ or $y'$ at all.

Answer (score 2):

The integral in your expression for $U(\mathbf{r})$ should be a *path integral*.

Fortunately, since you know that this force is conservative, $U$ must be path-independent, so you can simply choose whichever path is easiest for you. I'll demonstrate three of them. The arrows represent motion in straight lines between the specified points. Additionally, $x'$ and $y'$ are the coordinates of $\mathbf{r}$ and are *constants* for our purposes, while $x$ and $y$ are integration *variables*.

**Path 1: $(0,0,0)\to(0,y',0)\to(x',y',0)$**

First, move vertically, then move horizontally. This splits your path integral into two segments. For the first segment, $\mathbf{dr}=(0,dy,0)$, and for the second segment, $\mathbf{dr}=(dx,0,0)$.

**Path 2: $(0,0,0)\to(x',0,0)\to(x',y',0)$**

First, move horizontally, then move vertically. This splits your path integral into two segments. For the first segment, $\mathbf{dr}=(dx,0,0)$, and for the second segment, $\mathbf{dr}=(0,dy,0)$.

**Path 3: $(0,0,0)\to(x',y',0)$**

Move diagonally. We parametrize this path by choosing a parameter $t$ such that $x=tx'$ and $y=ty'$, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ along the path. This also means that $dx=x'\;dt$ and $dy=y'\;dt$, so $\mathbf{dr}=(dx,dy,dz)=(x',y',0)dt$. We skipped this step before, because the paths were already parametrized by the coordinates.

Note that the path doesn't even have to be linear - the only requirement is that it's continuous! Nonlinear paths are almost always harder to work with, especially in these simple situations, but there are always some pathological problems where they may make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

We know that,

$\vec {F}=-\nabla U$ or

$$F_{x}=-\frac{\partial  U}{\partial x}$$ 
$$F_{y}=-\frac{\partial  U}{\partial y}$$
$$F_{z}=-\frac{\partial  U}{\partial z}$$

so we can write,

$$U(x,y,z)=-\int F_x dx + U(y,z)$$
or
$$U(x,y,z)=-xy + U(y,z)$$

now we can do the same thing for other parts.

$$U(x,y,z)=-\int F_y dy + U(x,z)$$

or 
$$U(x,y,z)=-xy + U(x,z)$$

and finally,

$$U(x,y,z)=-\int F_z dz + U(y,x)$$

$$U(x,y,z)=U(x,y)$$

Since theres only one unique solution we can write,

$$U(x,y,z)=-xy$$

Answer (score 0):

If you start at the origin the first path will be along either the x-axis or the y-axis and the work done will be zero.
Eg from $(0,0)$ to $(0,y)$ the work done is $\vec F \cdot \Delta \vec y \Rightarrow (y\,\hat x + 0\,\hat y)\cdot (y-0)\, \hat y =0$

Then the next amount of work done to get to $(x,y)$  will be $xy$.
Eg from $(0,y)$ to $(x,y)$ the work done is $\vec F \cdot \Delta \vec x \Rightarrow (y\,\hat x + x\,\hat y)\cdot (x-0)\, \hat x =xy$ with the variation in the $\hat y$ component of the force ignored as the path is perpendicular to that component.

[image].

Answer (score -1):

Simply:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
F_{x}=-\frac{\partial d U}{\partial x}=y \\ 
F_{y}=-\frac{\partial d U}{\partial y}=x \\ 
F_{z}=-\frac{\partial d U}{\partial z}=0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
$$\rightarrow U(x,y,z)=-xy+kost$$

Comment: I know this way works, but I have to use the integral to calculate the potential energy.